# Disable button not woking

Tags: javascript

I have a function that displays a textbox, but my button is not disable when im not typing in textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    loadData();    
    function loadData(is_category) {   
        $(document).on('click', '.viewdetails', function () {
            var html = '';
            html += '<input type=text id="ConvoDetails">'<input type="submit" class="sendButton">';    
        },

        $('.sendButton').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#ConvoDetails').keyup(function () {
        $('.sendButton').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
    });            
});
```

Comment: Your JS is syntactically invalid. Please try to debug your code on your own before you ask on SO!

Answer (score 0):

Short fix:

```
$('.sendButton').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

However, you might want to change your code to bind to `change` event instead of `keyup`. `keyup` is fired way too often for your needs and it might cause lags.

Answer (score 0):

In your input html you can catch the key up element like this `<input type=text id="ConvoDetails" onkeyup="onInputKeyUp(this)` and then a function that handles the event like this `onInputKeyUp(element) {}`.

Also, you don't need this line of code `$('.sendButton').prop('disabled', true);` if you set your input button by default as disable like this `<input type="submit" class="sendButton" disable>`

The full code example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  loadData();

    function loadData(is_category) {

    $(document).on('click', '.viewdetails', function () {

        var html = '';
        html += '<input type=text id="ConvoDetails" onkeyup="onInputKeyUp(this)"><input type="submit" class="sendButton" disable>';
    });
});

onInputKeyUp(element) {
    element.disabled = element.value == "";
}
```

Comment: how can i use this ? onInputKeyUp(element) {
    element.disabled = element.value == "";
} ?  it displays an error (; expected )